# Translation possible pour le mot anglais “Outworld”?

Tags: expressions, vocabulaire, traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot

J’essaie de traduire le mot “Outworld”, qui est un terme marketing, pour le site Web de notre entreprise mais je n’ai trouvé seulement “Outremonde” et “Extraversion”. Je ne crois pas que ce soit les bonnes traductions en terme “Marketing”.

On veut dire par “Outworld” qu’on est ouvert à faire des partenariats avec d’autres entreprises. C’est exactement “Outworld Oriented”.

Je serai reconnaissant si vous pouvez m’aider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On peut simplement dire *ouvert aux partenariats*. Voire *orienté partenariats* (ce qui sonne alors très "jargon e-marketing 2.0 branché").

Comment: Oui, bien sûr, c'est mieux que ma proposition !

Answer (score 2):

Bonjour
je pense que le mot que tu cherche est Outward et non pas Outworld.

Outward :  vers l'extérieur , en partance 
Outward payment :  décaissement

ou bien un autre mot : Outwork : travail à domicile

Comment: Ce devrait être un commentaire à la question plutôt qu'une réponse mais c'est une remarque très juste. *Outward-oriented* apparaît comme une expression courante alors que *Outword oriented* n'a qu'une poignée de hits...

Answer (score 1):

La traduction la plus directe est *monde extérieur* donc ici *ouverts au monde extérieur*.

Edit: comme il s'agit en fait de ***outward**-oriented*, il n'est plus question de monde et on peut dire:

> une stratégie
>
> - ouverte sur l'extérieur
> - tournée vers l'extérieur
> - orientée vers l'extérieur

Comment: Mais vous croyez que c’est plutôt un terme “marketing”?

Comment: Non, c'est un terme générique. Rien n'interdit cependant de l'utiliser dans ce contexte.